# Missing images in 4.1.2 release

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I decidet to try agile toolkit as platform to develop our new service and downloaded and installed the zip (4.1.2 version).

I made a quick setup on our developement server (apache, php 5.3.2, mysql 5.3) and start testing an index page with subscription and login following some of the samples.

When I submit the form with some mandatory filed missing the browser console complains that an images is missing (atk4/templates/default/images/ui-icons-red.png), I suppose is the exclamation red icon...

I have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filled a issue report: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/20. It's fixed in development branch and will be out with new version.

Meanwhile, create directory atk4/templates/default/images and copy file atk4/templates/shared/images/ui-icons-red.png in there.

Thanks for bringing this to attention, although please do use github's issue reporting system next time, stackoverflow is not for bug reports.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow and I tried the official atk4 site but the contact form was unaccesible... Next time I'll check github :)